# Requester pays model for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-billing

AWS S3 has a requester pays model -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html.

Is there an equivalent for AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no requester-pays model for AWS Lambda. Nor am I aware of it being available for anything except Amazon S3.

**Side-note:** The Requester-Pays option in Amazon S3 still requires somebody with an AWS Account to authenticate the request. The Data Transfer cost will be charged to the requesting account.